# NavigateToString not working on startup

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have this simple code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    wbInhoudstafel.NavigateToString("<html><body><h1>test</h1></body></html>");
}
```

It used to work, but for some reason it doesn't work anymore :( Is there an option that could modify it's behavior?

The thing is, if I trigger an event in my application where I set the exact same string to the webbrowser element. It works..

And if I use .Navigate("http://www.google.com") after initialize it also works... Really don't get why it suddenly stopped working :s

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work?  Does it not compile or is there an error message when you call the method?

Comment: You don't *really* have that string as the content, do you?  Also note that the method requires a .NET service pack, either 3.0 SP1 or 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to wait until the `WebBrowser` has finished loading.

```
private void wbInhoudstafel_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wbInhoudstafel.NavigateToString("<html><body><h1>test</h1></body></html>");
}
```

Comment: nice, it worked. I just wonder why it worked at first without this... But thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer doesn't work for anyone else too, try using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` inside the `Loaded` event handler:

```
private void WB_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
  {
    WB.NavigateToString("<html><body>This works!</body></html>");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, in my case WebBrowser_Loaded event gets never called.
I am talking about System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser which is what this question is about.